# Sending multiple Files or folder using node.js Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

So my problem is i was originally serving my files i believe static using

```
app.use(express.static(clientPath));
```

Since then i realised i need to get some pentameters from the connecting url.
now when i use the connection as below i only get the index.html so there is no css with it or any images so i was wondering how i can send all my files in the client folder?

```
 app.get('/username/:userID/hash/:hash', function (req,res) {
   
       var userDetails = {
           username : req.params.userID,
           hash : req.params.hash    
       }
  
       res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/../client/index.html'));
  
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Continue to use the static module to serve static files.

Make sure that the URLs you use to reference CSS, images, etc are still correct (since the URL of the HTML document has changed so relative paths will resolve differently).

Comment: I don't understand how the Url would change so i am struggling to put in the correct path to the main.css which was originally in the same directory as my index.html

Comment: The URL of the HTML document would have been `/` but you changed it to `/username/123/hash/asdf` so if you had `src="foo.jpeg"` that would have originally resolved as `/foo.jpeg` but would no resolve as `/username/123/hash/foo.jpeg`

Comment: okay cool that makes sense. how will /:userID/ and /:hash/ affect what i should type in the html document as they will be different for each user

Comment: They won't really, since the absolute URL to the image won't change. Use an absolute path instead of a relative one.